# Latest 1.6 Apache Shiro release problems

Tags: shiro

I've just updated my website to the 1.6 release of shiro. Now I keep getting lots of errors when you try to log in with the credentials for the first time. It implements taglib prefix="fmt" tag library for translation, it seems this may cause the problems. Did someone experienced the same?

Error trace

```
HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request
Type Status Report

Message Invalid request

Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to 
something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request 
syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/9.0.37 (8.0.4)
```

In details: when I first fire up tomcat and try to login, the site language is set to locale and it gives me error. When I switch to english the error disappear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended you disable Url rewriting:

If you are using a shiro.ini it would look something like this

```
shiro.sessionManager.sessionIdUrlRewritingEnabled = false
```

To restore the previous 1.6.0 behavior see this section of the documentation.
https://shiro.apache.org/web.html#global-filters

The next release of Shiro will fix this conflict, until then, you will need to disable one or the other.